# EventDispatcher in EaselJS

Tags: easeljs

The following code is correct?

```
function MyClass()
{
    createjs.EventDispatcher.initialize(this);
    var _that = this;
    ...
    function _onCompletedFunc()
    {
        var user_event = new createjs.Event("completed");
        user_event.label = "my label";
        _that.dispatchEvent(user_event);
    }
}
```

I correctly understand EventDispatcher in EaselJS?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This looks ok, although the approach is a little odd. Does it not work? Here is a quick sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/b6b6ddqo/

The main issue with this approach is that the "_onCompletedFunc" is not a member of the class, it just exists in the scope of the MyClass constructor. This means only that method can call it. A perhaps better approach is to put it on the prototype.

```
MyClass.prototype._onCompletedFunc = function() {
  var user_event = new createjs.Event("completed");
  user_event.label = "my label";
  this.dispatchEvent(user_event);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/b6b6ddqo/2/

Hope that helps!